# Why this SOAP web services doesn't work as expected?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I am pretty new in **SOAP** web services and I have the following problem trying to use a **WSDL** into **SoapUI**.

Into an application on which I have to work I found this **WSDL** file that should be the web services contract that my application should use to retrieve some data (it is a meteo forecast web service):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://www.webserviceX.NET" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
      <s:element name="GetWeather">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CityName" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CountryName" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="GetWeatherResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetWeatherResult" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="GetCitiesByCountry">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CountryName" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="GetCitiesByCountryResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetCitiesByCountryResult" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="string" nillable="true" type="s:string" />
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="GetWeatherSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetWeather" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetWeatherSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetWeatherResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetCitiesByCountrySoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCitiesByCountry" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetCitiesByCountrySoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCitiesByCountryResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetWeatherHttpGetIn">
    <wsdl:part name="CityName" type="s:string" />
    <wsdl:part name="CountryName" type="s:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetWeatherHttpGetOut">
    <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetCitiesByCountryHttpGetIn">
    <wsdl:part name="CountryName" type="s:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetCitiesByCountryHttpGetOut">
    <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetWeatherHttpPostIn">
    <wsdl:part name="CityName" type="s:string" />
    <wsdl:part name="CountryName" type="s:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetWeatherHttpPostOut">
    <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetCitiesByCountryHttpPostIn">
    <wsdl:part name="CountryName" type="s:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetCitiesByCountryHttpPostOut">
    <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="GlobalWeatherSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetWeather">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Get weather report for all major cities around the world.</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetWeatherSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetWeatherSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCitiesByCountry">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Get all major cities by country name(full / part).</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetCitiesByCountrySoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetCitiesByCountrySoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:portType name="GlobalWeatherHttpGet">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetWeather">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Get weather report for all major cities around the world.</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetWeatherHttpGetIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetWeatherHttpGetOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCitiesByCountry">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Get all major cities by country name(full / part).</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetCitiesByCountryHttpGetIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetCitiesByCountryHttpGetOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:portType name="GlobalWeatherHttpPost">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetWeather">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Get weather report for all major cities around the world.</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetWeatherHttpPostIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetWeatherHttpPostOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCitiesByCountry">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Get all major cities by country name(full / part).</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetCitiesByCountryHttpPostIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetCitiesByCountryHttpPostOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="GlobalWeatherSoap" type="tns:GlobalWeatherSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetWeather">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetWeather" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCitiesByCountry">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="GlobalWeatherSoap12" type="tns:GlobalWeatherSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetWeather">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetWeather" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCitiesByCountry">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="GlobalWeatherHttpGet" type="tns:GlobalWeatherHttpGet">
    <http:binding verb="GET" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetWeather">
      <http:operation location="/GetWeather" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <http:urlEncoded />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCitiesByCountry">
      <http:operation location="/GetCitiesByCountry" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <http:urlEncoded />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="GlobalWeatherHttpPost" type="tns:GlobalWeatherHttpPost">
    <http:binding verb="POST" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetWeather">
      <http:operation location="/GetWeather" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <mime:content type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCitiesByCountry">
      <http:operation location="/GetCitiesByCountry" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <mime:content type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="GlobalWeather">
    <wsdl:port name="GlobalWeatherSoap" binding="tns:GlobalWeatherSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="GlobalWeatherSoap12" binding="tns:GlobalWeatherSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="GlobalWeatherHttpGet" binding="tns:GlobalWeatherHttpGet">
      <http:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="GlobalWeatherHttpPost" binding="tns:GlobalWeatherHttpPost">
      <http:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

So, in SoapUI I correctly created a new Soap project using this WSDL and I am obtaining this project:

[image]

The main problem is that this web service seems to be not completly working, I tried with SoapUI but I obtain the same results with the web interface provided at this URL

http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx

Opening this URL there are the 2 possible request:

Selecting the first one **GetCitiesByCountry** (http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?op=GetCitiesByCountry) I can insert a country (for example **Italy**) and it works fine...I am obtaining the list of all the italian city, something like this:

```
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
<NewDataSet> <Table> <Country>Italy</Country> <City>Amendola</City> </Table> <Table> <Country>Italy</Country> <City>Crotone</City> </Table> <Table> <Country>Italy</Country> <City>Bari / Palese Macchie</City> </Table> <Table> <Country>Italy</Country> <City>Monte S. Angelo</City> </Table> <Table> <Country>Italy</Country> <City>Grottaglie</City> </Table> ..............................................................
..............................................................
..............................................................
```

Ok, great...it works...now I want to obtain the weather forecast of one of this city so I try with the second request provided by this web service, this link: http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather

So I insert **Italy** as value for the **CityName** parameter and, for example, **Crotone** as value of the **CountryName**

Doing in this way (I tried for different cities and also different countries) I am always obtaining this error message as web service response:

```
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">Data Not Found</string>
```

Why is it not working? Am I missing something?

Another doubt is: this web service seems to be related to this **www.webserviceX.NET**, what is it? Is it something like a web service provider?

Comment: Italy is not a city it is a country and Crotone is a city not a country. Unless you have a typo in your question you got the values swapped around. It wont return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider issue with service itself...

I did the following:

1. GoTo **http://www.webservicex.net/**.
2. Click on **Utilities** -> **Global Weather**.
3. In **GetWeather** demo enter valid data. (New York, La Guardia Airport;United States) and invoke it.

I am still getting same error in demo as you got in soapui...